# Commutation relations for Dirac and Pauli electron

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I hope this question makes sense.

Let $\phi$ be a quantized Dirac spinor with four components $\phi_{\alpha}$, $\alpha=1,2,3,4$. If we denote by $\pi$ the conjugate momentum, then they obey the canonical anti-commutation relations $$(CAR) \ \ \ \ \ [\phi_{\alpha}(x), \pi_{\beta}(y)]_+=\delta(x-y)\delta_{\alpha \beta}$$ in a distributional sense that we won't worry about in detail. (The normalization will also be ignored here.) Write $\phi=(\phi_+, \phi_-)$ for the decomposition into two Weyl spinors. If I put $$\psi(x)=\phi_+(x) v_0,$$ where $v_0$ is the vacuum, then in some non-relativistic limit, I've been told that $\psi(x)$ will go to $\psi^{pauli}(x)$, the wave function for a single Pauli electron. Thus, the position $x$ and momentum $p$ observables acting on $\psi^{pauli}$ satisfy the canonical commutation relations $$(CCR)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ [x_i,p_j]=\delta_{ij}$$ (again ignoring the correct normalization).

My question is: Can we derive this $(CCR)$ directly from the $(CAR)$ above? Intuitively, I would guess yes, since the position and momentum of the field should determine those quantities for the particles it creates. But how does this go precisely?

I might remark that for a novice like me, the expositions of the Dirac picture in standard textbooks look only loosely related to the QM picture. Hence, my confusion.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean: the field operator for a fermion satisfies an anti-commutation relation, irrespective of whether you describe the electron fully relativistically (4-component Dirac spinor) or not (2 -component Pauli spinor).

Comment: The commutation relation between $x$ and $p$ has nothing to do with what it acts on, be it $\psi^{\rm Pauli}$ or your friendly wave function from QM instead of QFT. It is just because $x$ is multiplication by $x$ and $p$ is $-i$ times $d/dx$.

Comment: Carlo Beenakker: Yes, I agree. But does this answer my question of deriving (CCR) for $x$ and $p$ from the (CAR) for the Dirac field?

Comment: Abdelmalek Abdesselam: I agree with this as well. However, from a rather fundamentalist view, the representation of position and momentum you describe is a *consequence* of (CCR).

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I'd be perfectly happy with a definitive answer that the two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: the way I understand it, $\pi=\phi^\dagger$ is the momentum of a quantum field, while $p=-id/dx$ is the generator of translations. These are different objects, see for example http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0206008

Comment: For a variety of reasons there really isn't a natural definition of the position operator in QFT. For one attempt see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton–Wigner_localization and references therein. You might also want to look at this paper by Schleider:   http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103758945

Comment: Dear Jeff, Many thanks for the reference. I'll try to understand it. But I'm not sure my question depends on the existence of a position operator for quantum fields. It seems to me that $\phi(x)$ and $\pi(x)$ still give the field density and field momentum at spacetime points. I could (vaguely) argue that they should therefore determine algebraic relations between positions and momenta  of various quantum mechanical particle states.

Comment: Dear Minhyong, $\pi(x)$ is the momentum conjugate to $\phi$ but it is not the space-time momentum. To get this you should look at the integral over all space of the momentum density $T_{0i}$ where $T_{\mu \nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor and $0,i$ refer to time and spatial components. The stress tensor is bilinear in the field $\phi$ and you can find expressions for it in any QFT textbook. The point is you need to look at the Noether current following from translation invariance to obtain the space-time momentum.

Comment: Ah! Part of my silly confusion appears to be resolved by your simple remark. I see now that this was essentially Carlo Beenakker's comment as well. I'll think about it more and see if I'm still confused.

Comment: Having thought about it, I still don't see that my confusion is so simple. (It's possibly even simpler.) I agree that the spacetime momentum will be obtained by integrating a density formed from the (local) spacetime positions and conjugate momenta. It still feels like the algebra of the latter will have a lot to say about the algebra of the momentum and position operators acting on the quantum state space. More precisely, it still doesn't appear completely silly to ask if one can derive CCR from CAR.

Comment: I agree, but the position operator is not a natural concept in QFT. QFT is a multi-particle theory, so you only expect to get single particle QM as an approximation in certain circumstances of low energy etc. I think Newton-Wigner tried to construct a position operator in such an approximation. The commutation relations of such an object with the momentum operator will certainly involve the CAR of the quantum Dirac field.

Comment: I'm quite worried about wasting your time with my remarks, but perhaps I will state my naive understanding anyway. Having quantized the Dirac field, even with a potential term, I can take a state in the corresponding representation space for the CAR with particle number one and let it evolve according to Schroedinger's equation w.r.t. the QFT Hamiltonian. But then, if I project the evolution to the single particle subspace again, I assumed I would get approximately Schroedinger time evolution in QM for an electron in a potential.

Comment: Maybe this is the point at which you're supposed to tell me 'shut up and calculate.'

Comment: Dear Jeff: OK, I think I've figured out how to write down a position and momentum operator just on single particle states for the Dirac field. I'll try to actually calculate before too long and see what happens. But I didn't shut up just yet so as to tell you not to waste your time explaining anything yet.